# Sophisticated string queries in MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoalchemy

I'm learning MongoAlchemy, a layer on top of Python driver for MongoDB. Let's say there is a Python class, mapped from a MongoDB object like this:

```
from mongoalchemy.document import Document
from mongoalchemy.fields import *
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
```

And i query the database like this:

```
for person in query.filter(Person.name == 'Geronimo'):
    print person
```

It works fine, but now then i want to query the database for case insensitive name (both "geronimo" and "Geronimo"), or to find all names having two o's in them. `query.filter(Person.name[1:] == 'eronimo')` and such do not work, as Person.name is not a string, but a QueryField object.

How do i do such complex queries in MongoAlchemy?

Answer (score 1):

To find any co-occurrence you can use operators within the query. Like this:

```
datosquery = datos.query.filter({datos.schema_name: {"$regex": texto}})
```

The `$regex` operator, which uses regular expressions, allows us to make more complex searches in text fields.

Here's a link to the operators for mongo queries.

https://charlascylon.com/2013-07-10-tutorial-mongodb-operaciones-de-consulta-avanzadas